# overwrite upon fileupload

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sql, html

hey guys, is there a way to overwrite any contents of a folder upon fileupload even if the filename isnt the same? I only want one image stored at anygiven tim, but I have no way of knowing what filename the user may upload so how would you overwrite in my code below?

```
 if (FileUploadControl.HasFile)
        {
            try
            {
                string theUserId = Session["UserID"].ToString();
                OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=localhost; Database=gymwebsite2; User=x; Password=x;");
                cn.Open();
                string filenameDB = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
                string fileuploadpath = Server.MapPath("~/userdata/"+theUserId+"/uploadedimage/")+Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
                FileUploadControl.SaveAs(fileuploadpath);
                string fileuploadpaths = ("~/userdata/"+theUserId+"/uploadedimage/")+filenameDB;
                StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";

                OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO Pictures (UserID, picturepath) VALUES ('"+theUserId+"','"+fileuploadpaths+"')", cn);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;

            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why not just delete the folder's contents before copying?

Comment: @Pekka, that's an answer in my book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say override it, why can't you just delete the old file?  This can be done with a filter on the directory list of types image, or by purging the full directory if the image is the only file in it.

Your better option would to pull the file name from the databse, as you are already storing the file name to associate with the userID.  This way when a user uploads a new file you can call up the current user record and delete the associated file and after the upload of the new file completes update the Picture record.

Finally, a third option would be to store the file in the database as a binary value.  And then every time you upload the image just update the image to the users Picture record.

[EDIT: More Details]

```
if (FileUploadControl.HasFile)
        {
            try
            {
                string theUserId = Session["UserID"].ToString();
                OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=localhost; Database=gymwebsite2; User=x; Password=x;");
                cn.Open();


//
//Something like this 
//


                OdbcCommand sc = new OdbcCommand(string.format("SELECT picturepath FROM Pictures WHERE UserID ='{0}'", theUserId), cn);
                OdbcDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                      if (System.IO.File.Exists(reader[0]))
                      {
                           System.IO.File.Delete(reader[0]);
                      }
                }


                string filenameDB = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
                string fileuploadpath = Server.MapPath("~/userdata/"+theUserId+"/uploadedimage/")+Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
                FileUploadControl.SaveAs(fileuploadpath);
                string fileuploadpaths = ("~/userdata/"+theUserId+"/uploadedimage/")+filenameDB;
                StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";

                OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO Pictures (UserID, picturepath) VALUES ('"+theUserId+"','"+fileuploadpaths+"')", cn);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;

            }

        }
    }

}
```

However, i must warn you.  Using code like this is very sloppy and insecure.  For example, using sql query strings with in your code opens your site to SQL Injection attacks.  You are much better off using something like LINQ to SQL or Entities to SQL.  On top of making it much simpler to read and write data to the database, it also provides data sanitation which prevents SQL Injection.

Also creating an OdbcConnection object from the connection string every time you need it is a slow process.  You might want to create a lazy loading singleton that returns a single instance of the OdbcConnection per session or application instance.

Then if in for some reason you do want to create individual instances of the OdbcConnection object, you might want to look into the using function.

```
using (OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=localhost; Database=gymwebsite2; User=x; Password=x;"))
{

    // DO some Work here with the OdbcConnection

}  // Automatically close and dispose of the connection object to avoid memory leaks.
```

Comment: any advice on how to do it? If I could use the database to find the current image in place and do some kind of delete then instead of insert do an update (which by rights i should have shown that code) my other option would be on page load look for any path not stored in my database and delete it but I just dont know the code how to do that or any of the options you mention? :S eek

Comment: Updated the response to include a code sample.  I typed this out in the text editor and therefore didn't test it.  If you are going to use my code, make sure you properly test everything.